# Hierarchical structure with (My)SQL database

Tags: mysql, sql, data-structures

I want to create a website where items are only available in specific areas/regions. 
The regions/locations where these items are available are selected by the following pattern:

1. Either there are states selected otherwise the item is available nation wide.
2. For every selected state there might be counties selected otherwise it is available state wide.
3. For every county there might be cities selected otherwise it is available county wide.

And so on... You probably got the idea.

Now my question is how would you implement such a structure with a MySql DB? Or is there an even better DB model with an suitable GUI ? (That would be perfect)
The number of items is fairly small (~20).

When the customer is visiting the page he would enter his location, and every item available for his location shall be listed.
How would a query for this purpose look like?

Many Thanks in advance, 
Flo

Comment: Relational databases are terrible at hierarchies. Maybe an XML, JSON or graph database is more suitable for this. On the other hand MySQL 5.7.8 has the [JSON](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html) datatype so you can use it as a JSON database.

Comment: I already guessed that JSON would be why more suitable here, but for some reason my client kinda wants to stick with SQL. Probably because that's what he's used to.

Comment: Or maybe it is because he just bought some silly webhosting package instead of a vServer

Comment: Technologies like MongoDB are not widely adopted yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a table `locations` with following columns:

```
id | type | name        | parent_id
 1 |    1 | State 1     |         0
 2 |    1 | State 2     |         0
 3 |    2 | County 1    |         1
 etc
```

In this example, County 1 belongs to State 1, and "id 0" is assumed to be "nationwide".

With that model, creating GUI for setting item availability is quite straightforward: you first query by `parent_id = 0` and offer it as a list, with additional `nationwide` as default option; if a state is selected, you generate another list, using selected id as `parent_id` and offering `state wide` as default option, etc. After user hits "save", get the deepest level `id` and save it in item table as `location_id`.

When it comes to actually getting the item list, though, it becomes less simple. For example, if your user says that his location is `County 1`, you should return a combined result for items that have `location_id` = 3, 1 or 0, going up the tree by parent_id. If you used an RDBMS that supported recursive queries, you could get those in a single query; MySQL doesn't support that, so you'll have to work around it by creating a loop to query `items` with specific location id, then selecting `parent_id` from locations, and repeating the query for that.

The negative side is that you don't control tree integrity with that structure. That is, you don't control that a city can only have a county as a parent - though you can create insert/update triggers to help with that. It's also possible to create a loop (by parenting items to one another), and it could potentially lead to problems.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) you can find a rather detailed explanation of different approaches to the problem. Basically your options are a) construct a ParentID/ChildID tree, or b) a nested set. Since, while other rdbms systems support recursion MySQL does not (at least not without the use of an elaborate stored procedure), and especially since your data seems to be quite static, ie wont really change much; I suggest you go the nested set way. It would make things for you much easier.